# Titanium cannot find Android SDK

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I tried to pointing Titanium to the android sdk but it says it still cannot find the directory.  I also use android in the terminal to install the lastest version, that work without a problem... But when I tried to point Titanium again to the directory it still send me the error. I tried re-installing everything and even that did not change anything.

I am using Mac OS X...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Have you downloaded all SDK versions from SDK manager ?

If yes than you just have to provide path to the root folder of android SDK. It will be something like android-sdk-*(your os name).

Give a try.

Answer (score 1):

What folder are you pointing to? When I installed this the first time I was getting the same issue. I would point Titanium to the folder for the version of Android I wanted. You need to make sure it points to the root Android folder.

Under Preferences\Titanium Studio\Titanium set the Android SDK to the root folder (for me it is: /User/Me/Documents/android-sdk-mac_x86

Answer (score 0):

have a look at that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443648/how-to-configure-android-sdk-for-titanium-in-mac-os-lion). start /path/to/android/sdk/android and install the sdks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem previously. I updated the `titanium studio` to latest version, and the problem is fixed. Hope this will help you too.