# How to Configure Android SDK for Titanium in Mac OS Lion?

Tags: android, titanium

I have successfully installed Titanium Studio. SDK Version:1.7.5[image].Now I have downloaded Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Now i am trying configure Android SDK but when i am Providing Path I am Getting Error like" **Could not locate the Android SDK at the given path**" I have attached Screenshot as well.

Comment: did you open the Android SDK and downloaded the packages?

Comment: you need to install the sdks like @Topener said

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1)** Download the android SDK From here.

**Step 2)** unzip android-sdk ( whichever downloaded )

**Step 3)** In OS X, there is no `/opt` directory by default. you explicitly have to create it. Run following command.

```
sudo mkdir /opt
```

**Step 4)** Run following command to enter `/opt` directory.

```
cd /opt
```

**Step 5)** Run following command to create link of android-sdk. Assume that you have `android-sdk` located under Applications

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/android-sdk-macosx/ android-sdk
```

**Step 6)** enter to android-sdk/tools directory

```
cd /opt/android-sdk/tools/
```

**Step 7)** or directly enter following command in terminal.

```
/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android
```

**Step 8)** select necessary packages & download them. Sample screen-shot supplied here.

[image]

Open this URL - http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/32161/problem-with-the-android-sdk-installation-in-titanium. They have posted a similar kind of Q-A there.

Comment: Oho...then you are also here to take Android gift :)

Answer (score 1):

and if you don't want fall in all this steps then just download eclipse and install ADT plugin for eclipse and download all the packages using ADT plugin.

You can get more info here,

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

I downloaded android SDK using this way in windows and mac both.

Comment: He is trying to setup android for Titanium & not ecliplse whole.

Comment: Yahh, i know, i have just provided a easy way to download all packages. Than he will just need to give a path to android SDKs root folder in Titanium.

Answer (score 1):

After googling i have come to know the all details of Installation of Android SDK in Titanium.Please refer this image.You can find this image at http://developer.appcelerator.com/get_started[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the directory which holds your Android SDK with the browse button. Type an ending slash ('/') after the path (*Android SDK directory*). Now you can select your SDK in the popup next to  *Default Android SDK*.

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate your Android SDK directory, e.g. `/usr/local/android-sdk-macos`
2. Create an empty directory named `android-7` within the platforms directory:

   ```
   mkdir /usr/local/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-7
   ```
3. Now try again and select the Android SDK directory within Eclipse.